# CSS: Align text within an anchor element

Tags: html, css

My HTML elements look like

```
<a class="myClass>
  <span></span>
  <span>Sample text with some long input which should break at some point the text</span>
</a>
```

Currently the result looks like

[image]

I would like to have something like

[image]

I tried to align the text `span` with either `text-indent` or with `margin-left` but none succeeded :-/ The approach with using a table and wrapping the content in cells causes some problems since its a list of multiple entries.

Initially I thought that shouldn't be too difficult but at the very end I didn't succeed :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use display: flex; on .myClass - see the [sample](https://%20https://jsfiddle.net/Stephen2hats/9aufoky0/2/)

Comment: Don't know why the simple `flex` solves the problem - but it does. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

just inline block them and align to the top [example](https://jsfiddle.net/7nau5yq3/1/)

```css
a.myClass > span {
  display:inline-block;
  height:min-content;
  vertical-align:top;
}
a.myClass > span:nth-child(1) {
  width: 32px;
}

a.myClass > span:nth-child(2) {
  width: calc(100% - 36px);
}
```